# Winsock - Non-blocking socket: send returning 10035

Tags: c++, winsock, send

From what I've read up about it, it means that the send buffer is full for the time being and you should try sending again later. That's where my problem comes in, how would such a wait function look like? I tried both WSAAsyncSelect and select but couldn't figure out how either of them worked.

Comment: 10035 is EWOULDBLOCK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select() is the exact right tool, just locate any kind of example online. Just note that WinSock doesn't set `errno` but uses `WSASetLastError()` when the example assumes a POSIX (Unix, Linux etc) system. If in doubt, the MSDN is the reference for WinSock, not the POSIX spec!

You could also use `WSAEventSelect()`, which has a few advantages but is also more complicated to use. Keep that in mind for now and use `select()`.

Comment: Must still be getting something incorrect, send stopped returning 10035 at least but no mater how long I tell select to timeout it still return 0. But if I tell the server to sleep for ~1 second it works just fine.

Comment: Oh, darn won't let me edit the last post, anyway: Got it work once I also set tv_usec. Even if tv_usec was set to 0 what's the reason behind that?

Comment: It's really hard to tell where the error is without looking at the code. Can it be that the connection is closed by the server or some other code?

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't be since I've set it up so it prints a message when disconnecting users, unless winsock would somehow auto close a connection without warning me about it.